# Emulation of an Orrery

Tags: solar-system, n-body-simulations, orrery

Orrery is a clockwork model of the solar system. I am trying to emulate one in 2D. Now, to emulate, I need to know what goes on inside. Can someone please explain the basic principle behind the clockwork? Or direct me to a resource that will explain all the machinery inside a simple Orrery.

Comment: orrery-related posts: [The Jupiter Effect Book](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/39194/7982) and in Math SE [How to predict the incidents of synchronization for multiple oscillations.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1812124/284619)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The principle is almost exactly the same as a watch or clock, but instead of three concentric axles, you need 9 for the planets.

Have a google for Orrery kit - there are loads available. It is really all simple maths - you just need to know relative orbital periods in order to calculate cog sizes.
[image]
(picture from [curiousminds.co.uk](http://www.curiousminds.co.uk/large-fergusons-orrery))
For moons, you do add a little complexity in the form of a transmission to support the Earth, so that the difference in movement can move the Moon.

Comment: Okay! Well after a whole lot of googling, I wasn't able to come upon a resource that would give me the gear ratios. Where do I get these from?

Comment: You can work them out pretty easily from orbital periods: 0.24 0.62 1 1.88 11.86 29.46 84.01 164.8 for Mercury to Neptune.

Comment: Also, a quick google for Orrery gear ratio comes up loads of results, including a set of spreadsheets with all the info you need.